# How to grab numbers from a cell in Excel

Tags: excel

How can I extract numbers next to colons in excel?
I would like to extract any numbers after : to a different cell.

Example below.

apple orange grapes : 3.68

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are loads of ways you can do this.

Here are 2 examples:

`=TRIM(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(":",A1)))`

`=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",REPT(" ",255)),255))`

and with VBA it would simply be:

```
Split(Range("A1").Text,":")(ubound(Split(Range("A1").Text,":")))
```